# I am receiving a key error when I pop off the generated random number key in python

Tags: python

I am getting key error in the code which I have written. The random number which is generated at the start is to be removed from the dictionary when assigning it a value. The random number generated value is being assigned at a later stage. This is the piece of code I have written till now.

```
import random
import math

def without_keys(my_dict,ex):
    for i in ex: my_dict.pop(i)
    return my_dict

period=int(input("Enter the time period: "))
channel_vacancy={'1':0.1,'2':0.2,'3':0.3,'4':0.40,'5':0.96}
num_channel=[1,2,3,4,5]
channel_selected=random.choice(num_channel)
times_played = {'1':1,'2':1,'3':1,'4':1,'5':1}
reward_arms = {'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0}
X_bar = {'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0}
A_bias = {'1':0,'2':0,'3':0,'4':0,'5':0}
B_index = {'1':1,'2':1.17,'3':1.36,'4':1.47,'5':1.66}
rnd=round(random.uniform(0,1),2)

vacant=0
t=len(num_channel)+1
particular_channel=[]

while t<period+1:
    particular_channel.append(channel_selected)
    if rnd<=channel_vacancy[str(channel_selected)]:
        vacant=1
        z=without_keys(B_index,[str(channel_selected)])
        for key in z:
            B_index[str(key)] += math.sqrt(2*math.log(t)/times_played[str(key)])

        times_played[str(channel_selected)] += 1
        reward_arms[str(channel_selected)] += 1
        X_bar[str(channel_selected)] = reward_arms[str(channel_selected)]/times_played[str(channel_selected)]
        A_bias[str(channel_selected)] = math.sqrt(2*math.log(t)/times_played[str(channel_selected)])
        B_index[str(channel_selected)] += X_bar[str(channel_selected)]+A_bias[str(channel_selected)]
        
        channel_selected=max(B_index,key=B_index.get)
        rnd=round(random.uniform(0,1),2)
        t+=1
    else:
        vacant=0
        z=without_keys(B_index,[str(channel_selected)])
        for key in z:
            B_index[str(key)] += math.sqrt(2*math.log(t)/times_played[str(key)])

        times_played[str(channel_selected)] += 1
        reward_arms[str(channel_selected)] += 0
        X_bar[str(channel_selected)] = reward_arms[str(channel_selected)]/times_played[str(channel_selected)]
        A_bias[str(channel_selected)] = 0
        B_index[str(channel_selected)] += X_bar[str(channel_selected)]+A_bias[str(channel_selected)]
   
        channel_selected=max(B_index,key=B_index.get)
        rnd=round(random.uniform(0,1),2)
        t+=1

print("The sum of rewards for each channel is: ",reward_arms)
print(particular_channel)
print("Number of times played for each channel is: ",times_played)
print("The B index for each channel is: ",B_index)
```

The error which I am receiving when I ran it for a time period of 100 seconds is given below:

```
B_index[str(channel_selected)] += X_bar[str(channel_selected)]+A_bias[str(channel_selected)]
KeyError: '4'
```

Comment: Have you searched what Key error mean? It means no such key exists. You can print B_index to see that. Maybe when you called without_keys() function, you poped it out!

Comment: I suggest you create a [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By doing so you will maybe solve your issue on your own and if not, then you will increase your chances to see your question solved.

Comment: If you're going to use dicts for keys 1:n, just use lists instead. Regarding your problem, when you call `without_keys()` you remove a key, so it's no surprise you get an error when you try to next access it. Why you'd want to do that is unclear though.